# Displaying different content view in the same uiviewcontroller by uitableview indexpath row

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to show different UIImageView in the same UIViewController depends on which indexpath row was selected in UITableView. I have an unwise approach which was created lots of UIViewController for different UIImageView, But i don't want do this. Is there any smarter approach can fulfilled that. You help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First add an `UIImageView` to the `UIViewController`'s view.

Create a `NSMutableArray` to store `UIImageViews`, and in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    imageView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```